# Spring localization truncates decimals

Tags: spring, localization

I'm using Spring localization with a properties file and basically want to localize `{0}€` with the parameter being a `BigDecimal`. The localzied output will show `1€` instead of `1.00€` while `1.01€` will be displayed as should be.

Is there a way to leave blank decimal places untouched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define message format for numbers this way

```
product.price = Price: {0, number, #.##}€
```

See [Dealing with Compound Messages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/messageFormat.html) and [MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)

Comment: `#.##` still doesn't show 0 values but you pointed me in the right direction and `{0, number 0.00}` did the trick. Thanks!